# Image format vs image compression algorithm vs codec

Tags: image, image-processing, compression, codec

I'm still confused with concepts of **image format**, **image compression algorithm** or **method** and **codec** and relationships between them.

In my understanding format is something image is saved in, so it could contain information about what compression algorithm or method (are these two synonyms?) to use. Or does a specific format always use the same algorithm? Also, these algorithms can then use multiple codecs but I don't see a difference between job done by a compression algorithm and a codec.

Am I right in my assumptions? Can you elaborate definition and relationships of these concepts?

Answer (score 1):

An **image format** is the specification of how the image data is stored on disk.

Since storage sizes for images can be quite large, images are often stored using a **compression algorithm** which can reduce the storage space needed to store a representation of the image.

A **codec** is an en**co**der/**dec**oder pair. So a codec *is* a compression algorithm, and the reverse de-compression algorithm too.

One place to start learning more is the documentation for the [NetPBM format and library](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/). This is one of the simplest image formats because it does not use compression internally.

Answer (score 0):

The following are examples of **formats** - PNG, GIF, TIFF, JPEG, BMP, TGA, PCX.

The following are examples of **compression** algorithms - LZW (*Lempel Ziv Welch*), RLE (*Run Length Encoding*), DEFLATE.

For the most part, each format generally uses the same compression, e.g. PNG format uses DEFLATE compression , whereas TGA and PCX format always use RLE. Some formats however can accommodate different types of compression, e.g. TIFF format can accommodate LZW, JPEG, Packbits, CCITT compression types.

A codec is more than a compression algorithm, it understands all aspects of the format... where to find the height and width, palettes, padding, compression, byte-ordering, transparency, meta-data and so on.

Comment: Can I say codec is an implementation of compression algorithm?

Comment: You can say whatever you like :-) I would say that a codec *contains* an implementation of a compression and decompression algorithm, but I would also say it consists of more than that - see the final sentence in my answer.